# Turn Character Into a Sketch

Tags: opengl, grease-pencil

I have a model of a man. I wanted to render it in some way so that it can turn into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfHjlA4iV4s) "This" is a pencil and paper animation, with each frame drawn, photographed, and archived.

I have seen someone else do [this](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/27354) in Blender.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Consider using Freestyle to render the strokes.

Answer (score 2):

### The Compositing Method

First, you could go for a cartoon render of your model. This effect uses advanced *Compositing* with the goal of creating a comic style look. You can read about it [here](http://www.minimaexpresion.es/?p=1070&lang=en). It can create results like this...

[image]

...but you'll have to deal with stuff like this.

[image]

### OpenGL

There is a way to render in Blender that uses grease-pencil. You can look into it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5TgaOuWu0Q).